# 0.625rem‬ isn't a valid CSS value

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, css-loader

I'm compiling my stylesheets with Laravel Mix.

When I add the following variable:

```
$font-size-micro: $font-size-base * .625‬;
```

The `$font-base: 1rem` so this should render a 10px font-size but I get this error: **0.625rem isn't a valid CSS value**.

Anyone with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your calculation in parenthesis like:

```
$font-size-micro: ($font-size-base * 0.625)‬;
```

Consider the following SCSS;

```
.xyz {

  $font-size-base: 1rem;
  $font-size-micro: ($font-size-base * 0.625)‬;

  font-size: $font-size-micro;
}
```

It should produce the CSS as:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.xyz {
  font-size: 0.625rem ‬;
}
```

Comment: Why would this fix the issue? Calculation seems to be alright: `0.625rem` is outputted in the error message.

Comment: The outputted value is 0.625rem* and not 0.625rem. Try typing this on [Sass Playground](https://www.sassmeister.com/).

Comment: I just tested it in the playground you suggested. Without parenthesis and the output is `0.625rem`. No warnings/errors thrown.

Comment: @LuudJacobs, interesting! I see the error on my compiler as - `0.625rem*‬ isn't a valid CSS value.`

Comment: But why are parenthesis needed in this case?
All the other equivalent calculations don't raise any error...

Comment: @ruinobreferreira, not really sure. But I have often encountered this issue. It probably has to be an issue with SCSS compiler. This happens usually with multiplication and division operators when used with units based values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was due to an invisible character.
I used the statement in the format `$font-size-micro: $font-size-base * .625‬ !default;` and the space was incorrect before the !default text.
I pasted it from clipboard.

Once I corrected the space the stylesheet compiled without any issues.
Sass Playground helped me to find the issue from Harshal Patil's comment above.